# Disable Windows snapping form when dragged beyond screen top

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have created a non re-sizable Windows form which is 800x600 pixels. My problem is that when viewing the form on a screen resolution where the height is less than my form height, the bottom part of my dialog is covered by the windows task bar.

I tried solving this by enabling the user to drag the form from anywhere using the following method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ReleaseCapture(IntPtr hwnd);

        const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        const uint MOUSE_MOVE = 0xF012;

        public void Drag()
        {
            DefWindowProc(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (UIntPtr)MOUSE_MOVE, IntPtr.Zero);
        }


        private void OnMainPanelMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctrl = sender as Control;
            ReleaseCapture(ctrl.Handle);

            this.Drag(); // put the form into drag mode.
        }
```

I was able to drag my form anywhere yet I have a problem now. Windows does not allow any window to be dragged beyond the screen's top edge. It snaps the window back to the top of the screen.

I am looking for a way to disable this windows behavior, at least for my form.

Comment: All of them.. XP,Vista,7 and 8

Comment: Didn't know there was a snap feature in XP.

Comment: Its not a snap feature, its just that it doesnt allow you to move the window beyond the top edge of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a small trick. Mainly be handling the ResizeEnd event and tracing the mouse pointer location between the MouseDown event and the ResizeEnd event. The difference is then added/subtracted to/from the initial form's Y coord that was saved in the MouseDown event and then simply just setting the location of my form to that coordinate.

I am still open to other answers if anyone can provide a different one as this cause some sort of flicker because of the location difference between when Windows snaps the form and when the code forces its location.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but i found this Question when i searched for a simple solution for this problem.

You don't need to calculate anything, just save a value and use it again.

Just save the Forms Y Location in the MouseUp Event and in the ResizeEnd Event, you set the Forms Y Location to the saved one.

```
int oldY;

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        oldY = this.Location.Y;
        Console.WriteLine("LMB Up");
    }
}

private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, oldY);
    Console.WriteLine("ResizeEnd");
}
```

Hope this helps anybody who searches for a simple solution to this Problem.